# Real time data exchange between R and Windows application

Tags: r, plot

I am using R for scatter plots, and now also for 3D cloud plots on top of an image.
I have an application that generates a lot of such 3D coordinates and I need to see those coordinates on top of the image at run-time (for debugging purposes).

Is it possible for my Windows application to communicate to R at run-time?

Comment: Can your windows application call code in Java, Python, or another language that interfaces with R?  Also, what does "real time" mean?  Do you mean the application will push commands into R periodically?  R is single-threaded, so you can't expect a plot to update with real-time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to interact with plots from external programs if you have control of the plot from something like rJava.

You might have a look at [the R wiki entry on the subject](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows#exchanging_data_between_r_and_ms_windows_apps_excel_etc).

Answer (score 2):

With Windows, you can also use [R-(D)COM](http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/projects/RDcom.html).